# Detagging with regex does not catch nested tags

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.4

In becoming familiar with Python 3.4's `re` module, I wrote a function with the intention of removing XML tags.  I wanted to make it recursive for alternate usage:

```
def detag(text,opentag='<',closetag='>'):
    t1 = re.escape(opentag)
    t2 = re.escape(closetag)
    regex = t1 + '+.*?' + t2 + '+'
    result = re.search(regex,text)
    if result:
        text=text[:result.start()] + text[result.end():]
        text = detag(text,opentag,closetag)
    return text
```

The problem is the function does not 'pair' the tags well.  For example:

```
>>> detag('a<b<c>d>e')
'ad>e'
```

The output I desire is "ae" (as these letters are not surrounded by open/close tags), but it seems the outer open tag is matched with the inner close tag.  I am curious as to how I can rewrite the function to get the desired output from `detag('a<b<c>d>e')`, and still be able to get the same type of output from multiple inline and nested/double tags:

```
>>> detag('a<b>c<d>e')
'ace'
>>> detag('a<<b>>c')
'ac'
>>> detag('a<b>c<<d>>e')
'ace'
```

The above examples are currently working as expected.  To reiterate, anything between an open and a close tag should not be returned.

Comment: This probably requires recursion, which is impossible for a regex. '<[^>]*>' match everything between the first < and the immediately following > with nothing, but it can't ignore nested tags. '<.*>' will just match everything between the first opening tag and the last closing tag in the entire document.

Comment: @chirokidz `s/impossible/really hard/`

Comment: @Biffen No, regular expressions describe regular languages. Regular languages are not recursive.

Comment: @chirokidz [*Some* regex engines can do recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), but of course it has its limits and gets tricky fast. But please don't take this to mean that I in any way approve of parsing XML with regex.

Comment: @chirokidz: I would probably be better off using find, but that kind of detracts from the goal of learning regex.  I was hoping it was something simple I was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: @Biffin Well, that depends on the implementation providing more features than the formal languages definition of a regular expression. Which is fine and can be useful, but importantly, the `re` module does not provide this functionality.

Comment: @noshelter For a simple pattern like < or >, find would be better, and as @Biffen points out, some regex engines in some languages do provide recursion. You might even be able to find an alternative regex module in python which provides recursive patterns, but `re` doesn't do recursion. If you want to practice regex more, I suggest picking a language or making one up and writing the set of regex's you need to recognize each token type.

Comment: More accurately, so-called "recursive regular expressions" are things that look like regular expressions but are REs with procedural calls jammed into them.  A parallel example is that Perl RE Extensions allow the `(?{ code })` construct to contain an arbitrary chunk of Perl code. Thus you could call it a "turing-complete regular expression" which is **not** a regular expression, you might as well call it a "turing-complete thingy" since you've lost all the technical sense of the term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), this [recursive pattern](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) could work:

```
<(?:[^><]|(?R))*>
```

At `(?R)` or `(?0)` the pattern is pasted from start. See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dT4xM5/1)

---

*Added by @noshelter:* Based on this information, the function could be adjusted as follows...

```
def detag(text,opentag='<',closetag='>'):
    t1 = regex.escape(opentag)
    t2 = regex.escape(closetag)
    re = regex.compile(t1 + '(?:[^' + t2 + t1 + ']|(?R))*' + t2)
    result = re.sub('',text)
    return result
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I have accepted the answer and added the altered code in your answer, but can't vote it up as I don't have the rep.  Which brings to question, why is the question not voted up?  It's a valid question and has a valid answer.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @noshelter Great that works for you and thanks for adding your sample to the answer :) I think it's also a bit of coincidence if q/a get's voted up, usually most happens during the first few minutes after posting. I didn't vote up immediately, because I wasn't sure if I understood the problem right and I'm not really familiar with Python.

Comment: I can't believe no one has mentioned [the pony he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) yet. This is a dangerously incorrect answer.

Comment: @msw OP want's to match something like `<a>` or `<<a>>` and not `<a>...</a>`

Comment: And when the OP does need `<a>...</a>` he may well remember this trick for unbalanced tags and find himself in a unhappy place. I think it at least deserves a warning. In case it matters, +1 from me because you do indeed speak to the precise question asked.